# Как правильно выделить память для массива собственного класса, определив собственные исключения?

Tags: c++, массивы, классы

Всем доброго времени суток!

При создании простых библиотек, для выделения памяти для массива класса я использовал такую функцию:

```
template<class T>
void alloc(size_t allocsize)
{   
    this->array = new(std::nothrow) T[allocsize];  // array - указатель на массив
    if (this->array == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("Allocation error in my class");
}
```

Но new(std::nothrow) считается устаревшим. Прошу подсказать, какие есть альтернативы / как правильно следует выделять память и прописывать исключение выделения по стандарту?

Comment: Ну вы просто заменили `bad_alloc` на `runtime_error`...

Comment: `new(std::nothrow)` не считается устаревшим. Мотивация делать собственное исключение для такого сценария непонятна. Это похоже на проблему XY.

Comment: Можно просто в try-catch завернуть выделение и выкидывать свое

Comment: badalloc это вполне себе отлавливаемая ошибка, почему бы просто как выше предложили не завернуть в try-catch?

Comment: Зачем вообще кастомное исключение? Взяли бы `bad_alloc`.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь! @DiHASTRO, я решил использовать кастомное исключение, так как посчитал bad_alloc неинформативным для библиотеки. Большинство классов (а то и все) стандартной библиотеки выдают собственные исключения и я решил, что будет правильным решением подражать им в этом.